# Upload file to server using android

Tags: java, android, file-upload

I am using the code below to upload files on server. But whenever I run this code my application closes unexpectedly.

Code:

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("Registered") public class UploadToServer extends Activity {

TextView messageText;
//Button uploadButton;
int serverResponseCode = 0;
//ProgressDialog dialog = null;

String upLoadServerUri = null;

/**********  File Path *************/

 String uploadFilePath = "/mnt/sdcard/";
 String uploadFileName = "service_lifecycle.png";

void uploadToServer(File file, TextView msgText)
{
    /************* Php script path ****************/
    upLoadServerUri = "http://192.168.1.3/media/UploadToServer.php";



    messageText = msgText;

    uploadFilePath = file.getParent()+"/";
    uploadFileName = file.getName();

            try
            {
           // dialog = ProgressDialog.show(UploadToServer.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                msgText.setText("1 : "+e.toString());
            }


            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
                                }
                            });                      
                      try{
                         uploadFile(uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
                      }catch(Exception e)
                      {messageText.setText(e.toString());}
                    }
                  }).start();        


}

public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


      String fileName = sourceFileUri;

      HttpURLConnection conn = null;
      DataOutputStream dos = null;  
      String lineEnd = "\r\n";
      String twoHyphens = "--";
      String boundary = "*****";
      int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
      byte[] buffer;
      int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
      File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

      if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

        //   dialog.dismiss(); 

           Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                               +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"
                           +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
               }
           }); 

           return 0;

      }
      else
      {
           try { 
               messageText.setText("1");
                 // open a URL connection to the Servlet
               FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
               URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

               // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
               conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
               conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
               conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
               conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
               conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
               conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
               conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

               dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
               dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""+ fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
               //-=----------
               messageText.setText("2");

               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

               // create a buffer of  maximum size
               bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

               bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
               buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

               // read file and write it into form...
               bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  
               messageText.setText("3"); 
               while (bytesRead > 0) {

                 dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                 bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                 bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                 bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                }
               messageText.setText("4");
               // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

               // Responses from the server (code and message)
               serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
               String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

               Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " 
                       + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

               if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                          +" http://www.androidexample.com/media/uploads/"
                                          +uploadFileName;

                            messageText.setText(msg);
                            Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "File Upload Complete.", 
                                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });                
               }    

               //close the streams //
               fileInputStream.close();
               dos.flush();
               dos.close();

          } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

          //    dialog.dismiss();  
              ex.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                      Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "MalformedURLException", 
                                                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });

              Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
          } catch (Exception e) {

         //     dialog.dismiss();  
              e.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                      Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", 
                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });
              Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " 
                                               + e.getMessage(), e);  
          }
         // dialog.dismiss();       
          return serverResponseCode; 

       } // End else block 
     }
```

}

And code for php is:

```
<?php

    $file_path = "uploads/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

And I am calling this method through:

```
void openDialogBox()
{

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("file/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);


}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // A contact was picked.  Here we will just display it
            // to the user.

            Uri uri =  data.getData();

            File file = new File(uri.toString());

            if(uri.toString().startsWith("file:/"))
                file = new File(uri.toString().substring(6));

            msgTxt.setText(file.getName());
            Toast.makeText(this, uri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            try
            {
                UploadToServer upToServer = new UploadToServer();
            upToServer.uploadToServer(file,msgTxt);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                msgTxt.setText(e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how but it uploaded two image files before closing down.
Any help is appreciated.

```
    03-07 02:24:35.092: W/Resources(2847): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f050003}

03-07 02:24:35.252: D/dalvikvm(2847): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 118K, 6% free 3265K/3448K, paused 40ms, total 45ms

03-07 02:24:35.382: D/(2847): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb80e2ae0, tid 2847

03-07 02:24:35.482: W/EGL_emulation(2847): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

03-07 02:24:35.502: D/OpenGLRenderer(2847): Enabling debug mode 0

03-07 02:24:40.332: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(2847): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection

03-07 02:24:49.832: W/EGL_emulation(2847): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

03-07 02:24:50.872: I/Choreographer(2847): Skipped 60 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

03-07 02:24:51.612: D/dalvikvm(2847): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 262K, 9% free 
3464K/3792K, paused 348ms, total 351ms

03-07 02:24:52.072: D/dalvikvm(2847): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 9% free             3553K/3888K, paused 410ms, total 411ms

03-07 02:24:54.862: I/uploadFile(2847): HTTP Response is : OK: 200

03-07 02:24:55.112: D/AndroidRuntime(2847): Shutting down VM

03-07 02:24:55.122: W/dalvikvm(2847): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a97b90)

03-07 02:24:55.122: E/AndroidRuntime(2847): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

03-07 02:24:55.122: E/AndroidRuntime(2847): Process: com.example.fileuploaddemo, PID: 2847

03-07 02:24:55.122: E/AndroidRuntime(2847): java.lang.NullPointerException

03-07 02:24:55.122: E/AndroidRuntime(2847):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)

03-07 02:24:55.122: E/AndroidRuntime(2847):     at     android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)

03-07 02:24:55.122: E/AndroidRuntime(2847):     at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:93)

03-07 02:24:55.122: E/AndroidRuntime(2847):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:241)

03-07 02:24:55.122: E/AndroidRuntime(2847):     at com.example.fileuploaddemo.UploadToServer$9.run(UploadToServer.java:239)

03-07 02:24:55.122: E/AndroidRuntime(2847):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)

03-07 02:24:55.122: E/AndroidRuntime(2847):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

03-07 02:24:55.122: E/AndroidRuntime(2847):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

03-07 02:24:55.122: E/AndroidRuntime(2847):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)

03-07 02:24:55.122: E/AndroidRuntime(2847):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

03-07 02:24:55.122: E/AndroidRuntime(2847):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

03-07 02:24:55.122: E/AndroidRuntime(2847):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)

03-07 02:24:55.122: E/AndroidRuntime(2847):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)

03-07 02:24:55.122: E/AndroidRuntime(2847):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

03-07 02:24:58.642: I/Process(2847): Sending signal. PID: 2847 SIG: 9
```

And whenvever I comment the following part of code it works fine, no error, no unfortunately closing of app
Code:

```
Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " 
                       + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);


               if(serverResponseCode == 200)
               {

                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                          +" http://www.androidexample.com/media/uploads/"
                                          +uploadFileName;

                            messageText.setText(msg);
                            Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "File Upload Complete.", 
                                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                            });


               }
```

Comment: can you please show me crash logs.

Comment: What error you getting? could you please post logs

Comment: @user3335496  the log please

Comment: It will take time to provide log as I am using a real device for testing. I will have to look for setting up my avd.

Comment: Real devices produce logcat output too if connected by usb with your development pc.

Comment: I connected it with usb and used `adb logcat` in command prompt but it is not showing any error logs.

Comment: Make sure USB debugging is on, and for ease, use ADT logcat gui.